# Detect if own Opera extension installed and disabled using JavaScript

Tags: opera-extension

I can detect if my **Opera** extension installed by setting the new **window** object property  (**window.isExtensionInstalled** for example) in injected script and checking it in web-page javaScript.

But this is not solution in case the extension is disabled.

How can I detect disabled extension?

Are there features like resources web-access in same manner as for **Chrome** extensions?

May be some other useful features?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such feature.

By definition, each extension lives in its own sandbox and is not aware of other extension.

The only chance is to look out of the `window` (object) and search for footprints (modifications of the window or child objects) of other extensions.
If these are forced to stay at home (deactivated), the can't leave footprints..

Sry for being so figurative ;)